# "generic array creation" when fixing complains about unsafe operation

Tags: java

The following line of code causes `javac` to give an unsafe operation warning:

```
LinkedList<Node>[] buckets = new LinkedList[bucketCount];
```

However, when I try to fix that by doing this:

```
LinkedList<Node>[] buckets = new LinkedList<Node>[bucketCount];
```

I get a `generic array creation` error. How can I solve this?

Comment: @NPE I'm implementing my own hashmap for educational purposes.

Comment: I believe the syntax is List<Node> buckets = new LinkedList<Node>(bucketCount);

Comment: @NPE That was a typo, the type on the left is definitely an array.

Comment: There might be some good background information at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2927391/whats-the-reason-i-cant-create-generic-array-types-in-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a nutshell, [arrays of generic types are problematic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/897251/how-do-i-use-arrays-of-generic-types-correctly).

Turn `buckets` into an `ArrayList` of `LinkedList`s:

```
ArrayList<LinkedList<Node>> buckets = new ArrayList<LinkedList<Node>>(bucketCount);
for (int i = 0; i < bucketCount; ++i) {
    buckets.add(new LinkedList<Node>());
}
```

This way you'll get compile-time type safety.

Comment: Yeah, Java generics are kinda a hack, and don't handle this situation well.  But it's silly to have to go to using a non-array to circumvent an artificial restriction.

Answer (score 0):

LinkedList only has two constructors, one is default, and the other accepts a parameter which extends Collection,

```
public LinkedList(Collection<? extends E> c) {
this();
addAll(c);
}
```

this is to say that LinkedList cann't have a initialization size, if it's nessary to initialize the capacity of container,  you'd better use ArrayList, like following:

```
List<Node> list = new ArrayList<Node>(bucketCount);
```

Good luck :)