# Type safety: The expression of type Class[] needs unchecked conversion to conform to Class<Animal>[]

Tags: java, type-safety

I have this warning when I'm compiling the line.

```
private static Class<Animal>[] animals = new Class[] { Human.class, Dog.class, Cat.class };
```

What does it mean? How to correct it?

Comment: You should use probably use `Class<? extends Animal>[]`. If you use `Class<Animal>[]`, you're implying that every element in the array is `Animal.class`. However, `Class<? extends Animal>[]` says that every element in the array is a subclass of `Animal`.

Comment: Don't use an array. Use a `Collection`.

Comment: See also your options [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/897251/how-do-i-use-arrays-of-generic-types-correctly).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This means, that the compiler does not know if this Class gets Animal Classes assigned to it. E.g. it does not know if Human.class etc. are subtypes of Animal.class.
`Class<>[]{Classes...}` should probably work