# Override Java method generic with array

Tags: java, arrays, generics, overriding

I’ve a Service interface like:

```
public interface Service {
    <T> void print(T data);
}
```

When I try to override this method with array, I’ll get compilation error and it’s fine for non array object.
 
I know if the type T defined at interface level, both array and non array will work fine.
I'm not creating array, I just try to pass array as type.

```
public <String[]> void print(String[] data) //compilation error
public <String> void print(String data) // fine
```

Why can't I override with array?

Comment: [Java does not permit generic arrays](http://stackoverflow.com/a/897258/5129339)

Comment: @venture That code does not try to create generic array, but pass array as generic parameter type.

Comment: Java does not permit generic arrays. Check [http://stackoverflow.com/a/897258/1061601](http://stackoverflow.com/a/897258/1061601)

Comment: What is the compilation error that you get? Is there a specific error?

Comment: @CacheStaheli the message is error: > expected

Comment: That generic doesn't work the way you expect it to work.  What your `Service` interface says is that _any_ `Service` must be able to print _anything._

Answer (score 2):

That generic doesn't work the way you expect it to work.  What your `Service` interface says is that *any* `Service` must be able to print *anything.*  What you *want* is

```
interface Service<T> {
    void print(T t);
}

class StringService implements Service<String> {
    void print(String str);
}

class StringArrayService implements Service<String[]> {
    void print(String[] str);
}
```

What you're getting with

```
public <String> void print(String data) // fine
```

is *not* fine.  It's exactly the same as

```
public <E> void print(E data);
```

except the type variable isn't named `E`, it's named `String`, and it has no actual relationship to the `String` you expect.

Comment: Thanks for replying. Actually, I try to put the generic at method level is because I’ve a ServiceFactory which will return a specific Service according to type `public Service<?> getService(String type) {
    if ("STRING".equals(type)) {
        return new StringService();
    } else if ("ARRAY".equals(type)) {
        return new StringArrayService();
    }
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid type '" + type + "'");
}` The problem is whenever I get a Service I need to do casting and I also want to get rid of the unchecked cast warning message.

Comment: The serious answer is: too bad.  Your code is inherently unsafe.  The code I've provided is safer than what you have, but nothing is going to prevent you needing to do unsafe casts whether you like it or not.

Answer (score -2):

Actually you **can** override this with array.
The generic type can't specify a type of `<T[]>` because it suppose to indicate a type, and an array is data structure, but the argument `print` gets is of type `T[]` as an argument:
You can change a little your code so it will compile:

```
public interface Service {
    <T> void print(T data);
    <T> void print(T[] data);
}

...

public <String> void print(String[] data) //fine!
public <String> void print(String data) // fine!
```